# Find what process started another process

Tags: windows-7, process, process-explorer

Say I have process explorer showing me that I have an app called `EvilAppsRUs.exe` running.

I kill it, but it just starts up again.  I have checked to make sure it does not have a service (by right clicking->Properties on it in Process Explorer).

So, I am fairly sure there is another process out there (maybe called something benign like `DisplayDriver.exe`) that is starting (and restarting) `EvilAppsRUs.exe`.

How can I find out what the name of the process that is restarting the evil process is?

Comment: Try this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486717/finding-parent-process-id-on-windows

Comment: have you tried `process monitor` it's an utility that show in detail everything in relation with process, something like `ps auxf` in linux, if you try and it works please tell me to post this as an answer!

Comment: `ps auxf` for linux is amazing! Recommend it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, Using `process monitor` may help you. There, the  Process tree tool shows relationship between processes

You can give it a quick try In the [Official Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) ..

A very usefull real time. Process Monitor...

Hope it helps you

Comment: Turns out Process Explorer has it as well.  It is on the "Image" page of the properties of the process.

Comment: For those looking for that feature, it's in the top menu: Tools -> Process Tree (CTRL + T)